# Why does dynamic_cast need the base class to have a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast, virtual-destructor

I had the following code, on which I tried doing a `dynamic_cast`:

```
struct Base {
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {}
}; 
 
struct Derived: public Base {
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}
};  

struct AnotherClass: public Base {
    AnotherClass() {}
    ~AnotherClass() {}
};  

int main() {
    Derived* d = new Derived();
    Base* base = d;
 
    AnotherClass* ac = dynamic_cast<AnotherClass*> (base);
}
```

This led to the following error:

> the operand of a runtime `dynamic_cast` must have a polymorphic class type.

Making the Base class destructor `virtual` fixes this.

But why does the destructor need to be virtual here for `base` to be considered to have a polymorphic class type?

Since `AnotherClass` and `Derived` inherit from `Base`, aren't they already considered polymorphic types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Comment: Not a good dup': no answers mention `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: "_aren't they already considered polymorphic types?_": "_polymorphic class type_" in this context is a technical C++ term defined in the ISO C++ standard (see already posted answer for definition). It doesn't have (exactly) the same meaning as "_polymorphic_" does in programming language theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need a virtual destructor for `dynamic_cast`. The only thing needed is at least one virtual method in the Base class, to allow the compiler to generate `type_info` for the class hierarchy [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

But, you actually do need the virtual destructor, because without it you cannot properly release the resources held by a derived class when using a pointer to the Base class. In other words: `Base* b = new Derived(); delete b;` is *Undefined Behavior* without a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be the destructor that is `virtual`, but the class needs at least one `virtual` function to be polymorphic.